# Why is a cylinder Lebesgue-measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $C\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be Lebesgue-measurable and $h\geq 0$. Prove that $Z:=C\times [0,h]$ is Lebesgue-measurable.

**Sketch:**

[image]

Since $C$ is measurable, I thought that I could lift the set $C$ up to different levels $z=h$ and the set would still be measurable. A countable union of measurable sets is still measurable and thus $C\times [0,h]$ is measurable.

Is that a working method?

**EDIT:** I just realised that $[0,h]$ with $h\geq 0$ is an uncountable set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathcal M^n$ the set of Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb R^n$. Notice that $$\mathcal M^{n-1}\otimes \mathcal M=\sigma \{A\times B\mid A\in \mathcal M^{n-1},B\in \mathcal M^1\}\subset \mathcal M^{n}.$$
Since $C\times [0,h]\in \mathcal M^{n-1}\otimes \mathcal M$, it belong to $\mathcal M^n$.

Comment: I see, so, I just have to prove that $[0,h]$ is measurable.

Comment: This is rather straightforward because $[0,h]$ is a closed set, and thus a Borel set. @Analysis

Comment: Is every Borel set lebesgue measurable? No way :o

Comment: Yes of course. Since $\mathcal M^n\supset \{O\subset \mathbb R^n\mid O\text{ open}\},$ then $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)\subset \mathcal M^n$. @Analysis

Comment: Oh god, what a relief! Thank you.